# regex to trim down subdomain in the url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a regexp that match to something like : wiseman.google.com.jp, me.co.uk, paradise.museum, abcd-abc.net, www.google.jp, 12345-daswe-23dswe-dswedsswe-54eddss.info, del.icio.us, jo.ggi.ng,  all of this is from a textarea value.

used regexp (in preg_match_all($regex1, $str, $match)) to get the above values: 
 `/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,7}(?:\.[-a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})?/`

Now, my question is : how can I make the regexp to trim down the "wiseman.google.com.jp" into "google.com.jp" and "www.google.jp" into "google.jp"?

I am thingking to make a second preg_match($regex2, $str, $match) function with each value coming from the preg_match_all function.

I have tried this regexp in $regex2 : 
 `([-a-zA-Z0-9\x{0080}-\x{00FF}]{2,}+)\.[a-zA-Z0-9\x{0080}-\x{00FF}]{2,7}(?:\.[-a-zA-Z0-9\x{0080}-\x{00FF}]{2,3})?` 
but it doesn't work.

Any inputs? TIA

here is my little solution :

```
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$arrlength=count($matches[0]);
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++){
    $dom = $matches[0][$x];
    $newstringcount = substr_count($dom, '.');   // this line is to count how many "." present in the string.
    if($newstringcount == 3){                       // if there are 3 '.' present in the string = true
        $pos = strpos($dom, '.', 0);              // this line is to find the first occurence of the '.' in the string
        $find = substr($dom, $pos+1);            //this line is to get the value after the first occurence of the '.' in the string
        echo $find;
    }else if($newstringcount == 2){
        if ($pos = strpos($dom,'www.') !== false) {
            $find = substr($dom, $pos+3);
            echo $find;
        }else{
            echo $dom;
        }
    }else if($newstringcount == 1){
        echo $dom;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: If you need to split it... what about a simple substr with the first occurence of the dot? (.)

Comment: You want to achieve this just using regexp? or any method?

Comment: hey @Goikiu I have solved the problem, but it needs more refinement. will post my solution later. thank you.

Comment: @Jenson if I can solve it using regexp that would be great, so that I can learn more complex regexp. but any method will do for the sake of faster work. :)

Comment: here is my solution guys. (sorry for the ugly code):

Comment: here is the code : `$arrlength=count($matches[0]);
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++){
 $dom = $matches[0][$x];
 $newstringcount = substr_count($dom, '.');
if($newstringcount == 3){        
 $pos = strpos($dom, '.', 0);    
 $find = substr($dom, $pos+1);    
 echo $find;
}else if($newstringcount == 2){
 if ($pos = strpos($dom,'www.') !== false) {
  $find = substr($dom, $pos+3);
  echo $find;
 }else{
  echo $dom;
 }
}else if($newstringcount == 1){
 echo $dom;
}
echo "<br>";
}`

Comment: As this is kinda unreadable you should edit this code into your question (under the tags below your question there's a little link `edit`).

Comment: PLEASE don't use regexes for this class of problems.

Comment: From a quick glance, your solution looks good. If you're still eager to use a regex look at my new answer ;)

Comment: yeah your answer is great. will try that later. :) thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*(Caution: this answer will only fit your needs if you HAVE to use regex or you're somewhat... desperate...)*

What you want to achieve isn't possible with general rules due to domains like `.com.jp` or `.co.uk`.
The only general rule one can find is:

> When read from right to left there are one or two TLDs followed by one second level domain

Thus, we have to whitelist all available TLDs. I think i'll call the following the "**domain-kraken**".
<s>Release the kraken!</s>

```
([a-z0-9\-]{2,63}(?:\.(?:a(?:cademy|ero|rpa|sia|[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz])|b(?:ike
|iz|uilders|uzz|[abdefghijlmnoqrstvwyz])|c(?:ab|amera|amp|areers|at|enter|eo
|lothing|odes|offee|om(?:pany|puter)?|onstruction|ontractors|oop|
[acdfghiklmnoruvwxyz])|d(?:iamonds|irectory|omains|[ejkmoz])|e(?:du(?:cation)?
|mail|nterprises|quipment|state|[ceghrstu])|f(?:arm|lorist|[ijkmor])|g(?:allery|
lass|raphics|uru|[abdefghlmnpqrstuwy])|h(?:ol(?:dings|iday)|ouse|[kmnrtu])|
i(?:mmobilien|n(?:fo|stitute|ternational)|[delmnoqrst])|j(?:obs|[emop])|
k(?:aufen|i(?:tchen|wi)|[eghimnprwxyz])|l(?:and|i(?:ghting|mo)|[abcikrstuvy])|
m(?:anagement|enu|il|obi|useum|[acdefghklmnopqrstuvwxyz])|n(?:ame|et|inja|
[acefgilopruz])|o(?:m|nl|rg)|p(?:hoto(?:graphy|s)|lumbing|ost|ro|[aefghklmnrstwy])|
r(?:e(?:cipes|pair)|uhr|[eosuw])|s(?:exy|hoes|ingles|ol(?:ar|utions)|upport|
ystems|[abcdeghijklmnorstuvxyz])|t(?:attoo|echnology|el|ips|oday|
[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz])|u(?:no|[agkmsyz])|v(?:entures|iajes|oyage|[aceginu])|
w(?:ang|ien|[fs])|xxx|y(?:[et])|z(?:[amw]))){1,2})$
```

Use it together with the `i` and `m` flags.
This supposes your data is on mutiple lines.

In case your data is seperated by a `,`, change the last character in the regex (`$`) to `,?` and use the `g` and `i` flags.

Demos are available on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jB7aY4) and [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aqD_qKgL9tnKfiy2).
(Both of the demos have an explanation: regex101 describes it with text while debuggex visualizes the beast)

A list of available TLDs can be found at [iana.org](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db), the used TLDs in the regex are as of January 2014.

Comment: hahaha yeah I am desperate to learn. I just want to know if there is a solution this. I also thought about having a list of tld's. thank you for the inputs and the links. :)

Comment: But please just don't use it in production code ;) I just did this for fun... It will just break your performance... stick with your solution :)